# Spring-WS extract entire SOAP-Header in my spring inteceptors

Tags: soap, spring-security, x509certificate, spring-ws, payload

we have a webservice which uses soap security header like below.

I'm posting the header part alone which i want to get/capture/dump the entire soap header infos using spring inteceptors.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:per="http://com/myinfo/webservices/personservice" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-C65BABCE48EB203BE51445418168726378">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
     <ds:Signature Id="SIG-C65BABCE48EB203BE51445418168727381" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
           <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="aud per soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
           </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
           <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
           <ds:Reference URI="#id-C65BABCE48EB203BE514452344634628">
              <ds:Transforms>
                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="aud per" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                 </ds:Transform>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
              <ds:DigestValue>EdM5VqPByiliQndKko9KuNv1B2I=</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>b1JskNxbAat6oc4UfPOoNYEcVcYe2a7PKfPn/Ttn+unzzmywn/gwlqJwo38Rq4iWUdAPtUqeXEnp/F6U39V/tqg3OYUx6/FRT1yrqpyuLfuJGW9MW6laFZ2UCfJvFEe4QEUU4OdjXrTVmGy9PqFPCd8QBCmpbQfCyvr0nvuvFO0G5Rd0NAP45Bb276ieow7lGXMXIYkRmX956pmMdzrtzw9kneIcCaSqLZ9xBGExMuLErs0s6MAlCkYu3m84h4J7UlTpHtz2+LUZM0eOnPqU63xYVblnxwDs//nN8Tn4hC6gz1oGr4SC5wU8GjZjYBpTqy7nBfx7qMBQjjHDEX2D2A==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-C65BABCE48EB203BE51445418168726379">
           <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-C65BABCE48EB203BE51445418168726380">
              <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-C65BABCE48EB203BE51445418168726378" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
           </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
     </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Wanted to capture all elements between

```
<soapenv:Header>  </soapenv:Header>
```

How do i achieve using spring endpoint inteceptors

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your interceptor, you can use the following expression to get the entire `<soapenv:Header>` element:

```
((SoapMessage)messageContext.getRequest()).getSoapHeader().getSource()
```

Typically, you would then pass the `Source` object to a `Transformer` to transform it into the desired form, e.g. to serialize it and write it to a log file.

Comment: I'm Stuck up on how to transform, any help will be much appreciated.